# adding where clauses to a many many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, many-to-many, entity

I want to build a directory for restaurant, the search is based in three condition the problem that I have is add the third where clause that uses `typecuisine` like you see in code the 2 first conditions are good  [my entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOXAp.jpg)

```
var query = db.Restaurants.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
    query = query.Where(c => c.Nom.Contains(Name));

if (RegionId != Guid.Empty)
    query = query.Where(c => c.RegionId == RegionId);

//how to get typecuisine ID from table Restaurant instead it's only in  table TypeCuisine


if (typeId != Guid.Empty)
    query = query.Where(tc=> tc.TypeCuisines.Where(r=>r.TypeCuisineId == typeId));

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: `query.Where(tc=> tc.TypeCuisines.Any(r=>r.TypeCuisineId == typeId));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.Where` is expecting a return type of `bool` and you are returning the results of an inner `Where`, meaning an `IEnumerable`.

What you are missing is the `.Any()` function instead of the inner `Where`.

```
var query = db.Restaurants.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
    query = query.Where(c => c.Nom.Contains(Name));

if (RegionId != Guid.Empty)
    query = query.Where(c => c.RegionId == RegionId);

if (typeId != Guid.Empty)
    query = query.Where(tc=> tc.TypeCuisines.Any(r => r.TypeCuisineId == typeId));

return query.ToList();
```